# How to iterate array in JSON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm learning how to parse and play with JSON values with rails, but I don't quite understand how it's done.

**I fetch some orders from a Shopify API correctly:**

```
@ordersfetch = RestClient.get("https://#{ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']}:#{ENV['SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD']}@website.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json")
```

**After in my controller I convert it into a Ruby hash:**

```
@orders = JSON.parse(@ordersfetch)
```

**In my view, I'm not able print single orders, I don't get individual orders printed again, what am I missing?**

```
<% @orders['orders'].each do |order| %>
  <%= order %>
<% end %>
```

**JSON response gives me an array inside an object:**

```
{"orders"=>[{"id"=>3186507481285, "email"=>""...
```

Comment: It looks like you might be parse the whole response, not just the body. It's hard to tell without seeing the JSON response, or at least an example. What does `@orders = JSON.parse(@ordersfetch.body)` give you?

Comment: Hello Sam, I updated the code. I'm trying :
<% @orders['orders'].each do |order| %>
  <%= order %>
<% end %> but still I can't iterate over a single order.

Answer (score 0):

To access Ruby hashes keys/values use the `order[:id]` or `order['id']` syntax

Comment: Hello @arieljuod, I updated the question with the json response

Comment: I would suggest you use byebug and put a `byebug` statement right after the `@orders = ...`, then you can play with the console with the real object and get the right syntax. From the code in your question everything should work.

Comment: I agree with @arieljuod that you should inspect the response. I suspect what you want is `@orders = JSON.parse(@ordersfetch.body)`, because `@ordersfetch` will have other things in it besides the body (status, headers etc).  You should be able to iterate over @ordersfetch.body["orders"] like you want to.